# How to get value from <option> and use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

now i have the following code:

```
<form class="demo">
<select>
    <option selected>Selecione sua cidade</option>
    <option value='JP'>João Pessoa - PB</option>
    <option value='outros'>Outros</option>
</select>
</form>
```

What i need:

When visitor click on dropdown menu and select a option , they go to http://www.example.com
Each option will go to different adress.

Value='JP' goes to example.com

Value='outros' goes to example2.com

Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm using this

```
<script>
$('.demo select').change(function(){
 window.location.href="http://www.example.com";
 });
</script>
</head>
```

But still not working, and how to use to open different links:

Select option 1 = www.example1.com

Select option 2 = www.example2.com

Comment: If you're using `jQuery`, you should wrap your scripts within `$(document).ready`.

Comment: @jSang: *If* the code precedes the elements on the page. Otherwise it will work anyway.

Comment: @jSang Not required, he is executing the code `on change`

Comment: Ah @TrueBlueAussie, Mr.Alien, thanks for correction.

Comment: I was using jQuery, noted your tip, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mr.Alien Please unmark my question because was solved with different ways. Furthermore, I tried hard and had not found exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: @IslenoIturiel don't worry, your question will be linked to the main one which drives in more traffic.. Also, the answer you selected here is no different from the one I've linked with, the only difference is that the user over here is using function and over there, he is writing inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the urls as the values in the select, and call a function onchange:

```
<form class="demo">
<select onchange="go(this.value);">
    <option selected>Selecione sua cidade</option>
    <option value='http://someurl.com'>João Pessoa - PB</option>
    <option value='http://another.com'>Outros</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
function go(url){
    window.location.href=url;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is a decent Javascript-only answer. If you use jQuery however (as per the original), avoid using attribute-based events entirely as the separate the registration and handler code needlessly.

Answer (score 2):

why not you try something like this

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option selected>Selecione sua cidade</option>
    <option value='www.example1.com'>João Pessoa - PB</option>
    <option value='www.example2.com'>Outros</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should use a function rather then dumping the entire code inline which will be tedious when OP wants to change across several pages

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery val() function to check which value was selected.

```
form:

<form class="demo">
<select>
   <option selected>Selecione sua cidade</option>
   <option value='http://example.a'>João Pessoa - PB</option>
   <option value='http://example.b'>Outros</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
$(function (){
  $('.demo select').change(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it would be but it's more complicated than simple ifs :)

Comment: I thought OP wants to keep these values for some reason. If not then what you suggest is for sure better option.

Comment: For me the best option was steve answer but i really appreciate your participation! Thanks a lot bro

Comment: +1: For jQuery this is now the better answer.

Comment: I've edited question to make it using value instead of ifs. It does similar thing that @Steve answer but in Jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
<form class="demo">
<select id='drop'>
    <option selected>Selecione sua cidade</option>
    <option value='JP'>João Pessoa - PB</option>
    <option value='outros'>Outros</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
 $("#drop").change(function () {
    var res = this.value;
    if(res=='JP')
    {
            document.location.href = "http://example.com";
    }
    else if(res == 'outros')
    {
      document.location.href = "http://example2.com";
    }
    });
</script>
```